# In C#, is there a way to enforce behavior coupling in interface methods or is the fact that I am trying to do that a design smell?

Tags: c#, design, interfaces

Many times I want to define an interface with some methods that maintain a behavior relationship between them.

However, I feel that many times this relationship is implicit. With that in mind, I asked myself: **Is there any way to enforce a behavior relationship between interface methods?**

I thought about defining this behavior via inheritance (by defining a common implementation). But since C# does not allow multiple inheritance, I believe that many times an interface would be more advisable and that inheritance is not flexible enough.

---

For example:

```cs
public interface IComponent
{
    void Enable();
    void Disable();
    bool IsEnabled();
}
```

For this interface, I wanted the following relationship to be fulfilled:

- If `Enable()` is called, `IsEnabled()` should return **true**.
- If `Disable()` is called, `IsEnabled()` should return **false**.

---

**In that example, the behavior constraint that I would want to enforce is:**

- When implementing `Enable()`, the implementer should ensure that `IsEnabled()` returns **true**
- When implementing `Disable()`, the implementer should ensure that `IsEnabled()` returns **false**

---

**Is there a way to enforce this implementation constraint? Or, the fact that I am thinking about enforcing this kind of constraint is itself a sign that there is a flaw in the design?**

Comment: You are looking at it the wrong way. Based on the name, the Enable() method should **attempt to enable the component**. This may fail though, there may be requirements that are not met yet, initialization may throw. The IsEnabled() method on the other hand should **report the current state**. This is different and you should not try to make it the same.

Comment: @MartinMaat: just because the specific example is a little bit flawed, it is pretty clear to me what the OP is after. If you want to critize, it would be more constructive to suggest a better example.

Comment: @MartinMaat's comment doesn't seem like criticism, but rather pointing out that the OP's design is flawed. An interface only specifies *what* is implemented, but not *how*.

Comment: @DanWilson: the way I interpret this question is: let us for the sake of this example assume the design is ok for some reason and we want to enforce the described behaviour of the given interface. So is there a canonical way in C# which can help to do this (maybe not with interfaces alone, maybe with something else)?

Comment: The comment on the fact that I might be overlooking what `Enable` and `Disable` **should** do (as in, what a good design of IComponent would do) was very helpful. When asking the question, the possible flaw in the design is part of the overall question (I would not know if there was a problem in the question I am asking if I knew the answer!). In that sense, "Is there a canonical way in C# which can help to do this?" is equally helpful. Both answers compose a good explanatory answer.

Comment: @Albuquerque I would argue that you *shouldn't* try to enforce behavior on consumers for the reasons outlined in Robert Harvey's answer. You could very easily end up with constraint conflicts. For example, if `Enable()` fails, does `IsEnabled()` then lie and return `true`?

Comment: I have just rephrased the question based on the tone of the comments and answers received. Hopefully, the overall scope and intent of the question is clearer :) That being said, the comments+answers pointing the the problems of the IComponent design + the suggestion of using tests or DBC to ensure constraints make a really comprehensive answer, in my opinion.

Comment: I would argue for `Enable` and `Disable` returning `bool` and `IsEnabled` being used only to ease debugging. Although that could be just me and my paranoid actitud towards threading. Requiring the consumer code to call `Enable` or `Disable` and then checking `IsEnabled` would be a problem there is another thread calling `Enable` or `Disable` concurrently. Thus, that interface is not thread-safe ready (you could implement it in a thread-safe way, however code using it would still have to put a lock around it).

Comment: Sounds like you are asking for mixins

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Well, first of all, let's tweak your interface a bit.

```
public interface IComponent
{
    void Enable();
    void Disable();
    bool IsEnabled { get; }
}
```

Now then.  What could potentially go wrong here?  For example, could an exception be thrown in the `Enable()` or `Disable()` methods? What state would `IsEnabled` be in then?

Even if you use Code Contracts, I don't see how `IsEnabled` can be correlated to the use of your Enable or Disable methods unless those methods are guaranteed to succeed.  `IsEnabled` should represent the *actual* state your object is in, not some hypothetical state.

---

That said, all you really need is

```
public interface IComponent
{
    bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
}
```

Clear it, and the component disables itself.

Comment: I am choosing this as the accepted answer because it is what I chose to use. However, for future reference, [this answer by @T.Sar-ReinstateMonica](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/401619/349267) and [this answer by @DocBrown](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/401622/349267) were really useful and seem to be equally correct.

Comment: @Albuquerque: IMHO, a single `bool Enabled { get; set; }` would seem much clearer in terms of what it does and what it's supposed to return. Imagine how ridiculous it would have been if [Control.Enabled](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.enabled?view=netframework-4.8) in Windows Forms was split into 3 separate methods?

Comment: @Groo The author of the answer has just added the `bool Enabled { get; set; }`. Also, rest assured that I used exactly that in my solution. :)

Answer (score 39):

What you are looking for is a well-known approach called [**Design by Contract**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract). It was [supported directly in the framework in version 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260817/design-by-contract-in-c-sharp).

**DISCLOSURE: Be careful when adding code contracts to a new project in 2019. Current status of further maintenance by Microsoft is not fully clear, [see this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40767941/does-vs2017-work-with-codecontracts), maybe because of missing popularity.**

DBC allows to specify preconditions, post-conditions and invariants for functions as well as for interfaces, so you simply have to write a contract which enforces `IsEnabled` to be true after a call of `Enabled()`.

As other answers have pointed out, there may be alternative designs where these constraints are not necessary, but for the sake of this example, let us assume these requirements are justified for some reason. Then using Code Contracts on [Robert Harvey's variant](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/401623) of the example interface may look like this:

```
using System.Diagnostics.Contracts;

[ContractClass(typeof(ComponentContract))]
public interface IComponent
{
    void Enable();
    void Disable();
    bool IsEnabled { get; } 
}

[ContractClassFor(typeof(IComponent))]
sealed class ComponentContract : IComponent
{
    [Pure]
    public bool IsEnabled => Contract.Result<bool>();

    public void Disable()
    {
        Contract.Ensures(IsEnabled == false);
    }

    public void Enable()
    {
        Contract.Ensures(IsEnabled == true);
    }
}
```

See [here](https://www.dotnetcurry.com/csharp/1172/code-contracts-csharp-static-runtime-checks) for a short tutorial on code contracts.

Also have a look into [my second answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/401744) to this question, which offers a solution not depending on libs which may become deprecated in the future.

Comment: It is worth to note that the notion of DbC is _way_ more top level than a class interface.

Comment: @T.Sar-ReinstateMonica: sure, but where in the question do you read the OP is not after such a solution? I don't think Albuquerque is "asking too much of C# Interfaces", that seem to be only your interpretation of the question.

Comment: Oh, by all means, don't get me wrong. While my interpretation of the question was a bit too literal (I read it as "how do I force C# interfaces to do this specific thing"), yours opened up another possibility, and is probably the best tool for the OP. (I even upvoted yours, for that matter)

Comment: This answer certainly seems to be in the spirit of the question.  Some example code would make it better.

Comment: @Corey: you are perfectly right, but when I wrote it, I was a little bit short of time. Finally, here it is.

Comment: "It is supported directly in the framework since version 4.0." well yeah somewhat. In practice for all intends and purposes Code Contracts are dead. Not only has it not been ported to Net Core at the last time I checked, the required tooling also hasn't seen any official updates since Visual Studio 2015. I'd *strongly* recommend nobody to add code contracts to a new project in 2019.

Comment: @Voo: see my edit.

Comment: @Doc Thanks. As someone who was burnt by adding CC himself to several projects (and then removing it again years later when the maintenance hassle just wasn't worth it anymore), it's somewhat dear to heart to avoid others falling into the same trap.

Comment: @Voo Are there any current alternatives to CC?

Comment: @Zev Nothing with the same scope I'm aware of for C#.

Comment: Disclosure that the long-term support for Code Contracts is unclear should be highlighted. This being the most voted answer to this question will certainly encourage people to try it. (I almost did) and that should come with a "be sure you know what you are doing" warning.

Comment: Code contracts are used extensively in the .NET Framework Reference Source.  I doubt they are going anywhere anytime soon.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: even in the new .Net Core code base? I just found [this here](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/6361) on GitHub.

Comment: @Robert The full framework that is on life support and will only get new networking and security updates but no new features otherwise? Code contracts don't work with modern Visual Studios, the rewriter doesn't work with the new compiler and there's nobody at Microsoft who's interested in maintaining it. Just face it: Code contracts are dead in the water and have been for years.

Comment: @Voo: Oh, please.  *Winforms* is still in use.  If I had a dime ever time someone said [something] is dead, I'd be rich by now.

Comment: @Robert Yeah and WinForms is supported by .NET Core, its editor works just fine in Visual Studio 2019 and there's been changes to the code base in the last few months. Notice a difference there? Microsoft employees have publicly stated that there's no one left to maintain the project, the original creator left microsoft years ago and there hasn't been an update in years. What is your definition of "dead" if not that? If you plan to only ever use Visual Studio 2015 and never update your project to .NET Core/5 sure you're fine, but come on.

Comment: @Voo: My definition of "dead" is that it no longer works.  So I went and read the SO post and followed the bread crumbs, and Code Contracts is open-source.  While it hasn't been updated in years, there is [a project on Github](https://github.com/Igorbek/CodeContracts.MSBuild) that removes the hardcoded .NET 3.5 reference.  As long as there are dependencies in the .NET framework on Code Contracts, it's not going anywhere.  As with anything else, each developer has to make up their own mind whether or not it's worth the risk.

Comment: @Robert But does it "work" if it doesn't work with any tooling released since 2015, doesn't work with the new compiler released in 2015 and there's no maintainer left? I mean by your definition Windows XP isn't dead either - that's a pretty low bar. Do you actually use Code Contracts in any actual, current project you work on? I can't imagine, but I'd be interested to hear how.

Comment: @Voo: Do you have a reference for it "not working since 2015?"  Code contracts are present in the .NET Framework source, so if it doesn't work since 2015... ?

Comment: @Robert [You can't install the official tooling on anything older than VS2015](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RiSEResearchinSoftwareEngineering.CodeContractsforNET). You can very easily compile a project that uses CC in newer VS - you just can't do the rewriting or get static analysis which is the whole point. There are hacks to get the static analyzer to work in later  VSes, but that's not officially supported and you're completely out of luck with the rewriter when using Roslyn.

Comment: @Voo: That there's no support from Microsoft anymore was never in dispute.

Comment: @Robert As I said if "it works on 2015 era projects" is the whole bar to consider it "not-dead" then Windows XP is also still alive. But I don't think we'll get anywhere from here. Agree to disagree.

Comment: @Voo: My issue is not really your assertions about Code Contracts (which you've amply demonstrated), but that the full framework is on life support, which yeah, we're going to have to agree to disagree on that one.  Windows XP doesn't have anything to do with any of this.

Comment: @Robert Oh that. I'm sure the full framework will be around for many, many years no question on that point. Not many new features or reasons to start a new project with it, but I'd think it'll be supported close to indefinitely for backcomp reasons. Poor choice of words on my part there.

Answer (score 32):

**You're asking too much of C# Interfaces.**

C# Interfaces are contracts. They say what pack of methods a given class implements, and they guarantee that those methods *will be there* if someone calls them.

That said, that is also *the only thing* C# Interfaces do.

They are completely oblivious to what the implemented methods do. They are free to do whatever they want.

A given class can implement "isEnabled" to always return true. Another one can tie "Disable" to a database call, and refuse to disable if something specific happens.

You can't control any of that. That's not the job of your C# Interface.

---

**How do I enforce this behavior, then?**

Use tests.

Make a group of unit tests that can accept an object of the type in question, and tests the behavior.

If the test passes, you're good to go. 
If they fail, something is amiss and you should check your code.

That said, you have no elegant way of forcing this to a third party if you're developing an API, nor should you have. That's not what C# Interfaces are for.

Comment: An `interface` is not a contract, though it is certainly subject to one. Constants, variables, functions, `class`es, `interface`s, ... *and their behavior* form an *interface*, a particular instance of which is an implementation, and is subject to and hopefully fulfilling the necessary contracts.

Comment: @Deduplicator I'm not sure if we're talking about the same thing. [C# Interfaces](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/) can't have more than public definitions. They _certainly_ can't hold behavior, much less variables.

Comment: Although the 'no implementation' limitation is being relaxed a bit with C# 8 in the form of [default interface methods](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#default-interface-methods).

Comment: @EricKing That's awesome to know! Any timeframe for this to become a thing?

Comment: @T.Sar-ReinstateMonica It is already in Core 3.0

Comment: Yeah, C# 8 was released back in September 2019

Comment: Sometimes you use the term as if it meant *interface* as in API, sometimes as `interface` as in the C# feature. And when you switch you pretend the one you talked about before is the one you talked about after. It would be nice if you choose which one you use, switched more obviously, or marked which one you want.

Comment: @Deduplicator I'm only talking about the C# Interface directive. I never switched definitions, but I understand that some of the stuff I have in my answer might be unclear. I'll clarify.

Comment: An interface is a contract: That works with *interface*, not `interface`, though still isn't 100%. Oh whatever.

Comment: @Deduplicator Why not with a C# Interface? They are defined as contracts in several tutorials, explanations, etc. Why wouldn't they be contracts?

Comment: A contract is not only a bunch of signatures (types, variables, constants, functions, ctors, ...), but also the value / behavior, though rarely the specific implementation. That many contracts involve `interface`s means an `interface` is a useful abstraction, but doesn't in any way make the `interface` a contract. [...]

Comment: [...] There's a contract for every interface, class, constant, variable, and so on, or at least they have a small piece of a bigger more comprehensive one covering them, but that doesn't make any of them contracts. That contract can be implicit or explicit, public or private, shared or not, well-done or ill-considered, but neither of them changes the relationship.

Comment: @Deduplicator That's the (very specific) meaning of contract inside the DbC paradigm. There are other meanings for contracts, in the context of code. Yours is a valid one, but by no means the only one.

Comment: What Deduplicator is talking about is the fundamental idea of a contract between two interacting peaces of code (not necessarily within the DbC paradigm, but in general) - interfaces are part of it, but there are things that are expected from code that plays a specific role that the language used is not expressive enough to encode/enforce (so these might be documented instead, or be implied from the meaning of things, etc.). This is what Liskov subst. principle is really about - if code breaks those expectations, it can break the program even if it formally satisfies an interface.

Comment: That's the idea behind the often cited Rectangle/Square example (Square implemented as a subtype of Rectangle); the categorization criterion for type hierarchies is behavior. The math definition of Square being a kind of a Rectangle is not based on behavior, but on a property. If I write code that *relies* on the fact that `Width` and `Height` change independently (part of the contract), but the actual instance is a square, my code will break - even though both implement the same interface.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović Again, that's one (valid) definition of contract, and one that surpasses the language. I can also define my contracts as being my test suite, or my interface model. Those are also valid definitions of contracts, all equally valid. Deduplicator isn't wrong on his definition, but I stand that mine is also equally valid, if a bit more simplistic.

Comment: **... asking too much of ... interfaces**. Oh hell yeah!  Abstract classes &  methods and  template methods can go a long way toward guaranteeing temporal coupled method calls. Constructor parameters (i.e. dependency injection) can likewise ameliorate  no-multi-inheritance by compositing class behavior. Runtime contract enforcement is one thing, but `interface`s can only guarantee that sooner or later any consistent "base" behavior will get broken.

Answer (score 22):

State transitions can be represented by separate interfaces per state:

```
public interface IEnabledComponent
{
    IDisabledComponent ToDisabled();
}

public interface IDisabledComponent
{
    IEnabledComponent ToEnabled();
}
```

This is much more powerful and safe, since you can expose different methods depending on the current state. In particular you wouldn't even need the `IsEnabled` property.

Alternatively you could have a single really simple interface:

```
public interface IComponent
{
    bool IsEnabled {get;set;}
}
```

Here the state is represented in a single member, so no need to coordinate multiple related members.

You would chose the first options if the different states cause different behavior, the second if the enabled-state doesn't affect other behavior.

The fact that you can define a behavioral relationship between different members of an interface indicates that they are expressing the same information and therefore are redundant. To take a simpler example:

```
interface IComponent 
{
  bool IsEnabled {get;set;}
  bool IsDisabled {get;set;}
}
```

Here you could define the relationship that if `IsEnabled` is true, then `IsDisabled` is false. But this just shows that one of them could be eliminated since it doesn't represent any independent information or behavior.

Comment: But there's a powerful argument for readability by providing both options, even if they mirror each other.

Comment: @AdamB: I disagree. The convention in .net is to provide only the "positive" version of a flag property, i.e. `IsEnabled`. Redundant "convenience" methods may be acceptable on classes but not on interfaces, since this forces all implementers to implement redundant code which just cause needless complexity and risk of bugs.

Comment: Good point about classes vs interfaces.

Comment: @AdamB if you really want both Is/IsNot flag you can use extension methods for the second one (lack of extension properties makes code a bit strange, but …)

Comment: A caveat with the separate-interfaces-per-state approach: If you have an IEnabledComponent, and disable it with ToDisabled(), the IDisabledComponent is returned, but other parts of the code referencing the now-disabled object with IEnabledComponent would still have that reference and may erroneously believe the component is still enabled.

Answer (score 5):

One more option when you want usage pattern to look "traditional"<sup>*</sup> but can limit the interface so it does not require methods to be tied together you can use extension methods to "add" missing methods.

In your example interface can just contain `IsEnabled {get;set;}` and `Enable` and `Disable` can be extensions coming as part of your library defining the interface:

```
public interface IComponent
{
    bool IsEnabled {get;set;}
}

public static class IComponentExtensions
{
    public static void Enable(this IComponent component)
    {
         component.IsEnabled = true;
    } 
    public static void Disable(this IComponent component)
    {
         component.IsEnabled = false;
    } 
}
```

Note that since instance methods have priority over extensions and concrete classes may implement methods with same signature to force compiler to pick the class specific implementation possibly causing some confusion. On other hand pretty much everyone has significant experience with this pattern in LINQ - so worth considering if your interface can be narrowed down to allow it.

---

<sub><sup>*</sup> "traditional" interface in sense of people expecting to have some particular methods on particular types - for example `Stream` classes in Framework - one expects file to have "Open" and "Close" when regular streams just "new"/"Dispose".</sub>

Comment: Adding instance methods to classes that implement the interface isn't going to work because the consumer won't see them unless they are working with the implementing class itself.  If all you have is an `IComponent` then the compiler will use the extension every time.

Comment: @Corey did you every used `myList.First()`? or you always cast variables like `((IEnumerable<int>)myList).First()` before using LINQ methods for example? (Granted for LINQ this is actually feature...)

Comment: Sure, when I have a `List<int>`.  When I have an `IEnumerable<int>` then I call the extension because that's all I have.  I don't bother with trying to figure out what implementation I have because the extension handles that better in most cases.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another idea to solve this using a completely different approach than the one shown in [my other answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/401622) (hence I post it separately): utilize the **template method pattern**. Again, let us - for the sake of the example, assume the requirement to make `IsEnabled` work as described is justified for some reason, and you want to make sure it's state is updated correctly.

Then you could replace the interface by an abstract class, make `IsEnabled` a boolean property which is switched unconditionally (even in case of an exception), and let a user of that abstract class implement two template methods instead of the original ones:

```
public abstract class Component  // replacement for IComponent 
{
    public bool IsEnabled{get;private set;}

    public void Enable()
    {
       try
       {
          EnableImpl();
       }
       finally
       {
          IsEnabled=true;
       }
    }
    public void Disable()
    {
       try
       {
          DisableImpl();
       }
       finally
       {
          IsEnabled=false;
       }
    }

    protected virtual void EnableImpl();
    protected virtual void DisableImpl();
}
```

Now, users can override `EnableImpl` and `DisableImpl` by their own implementations, whilst the state tracking is guaranteed to be done.

This approach is definitely more standard than my first suggestion and I would not expect it to become deprecated by Microsoft soon.

Comment: Nice. You should not name a class `IComponent` though.

Comment: @Guran: ok, done. Thanks for the code review ;-)

Comment: This is the most viable of the answers I think.  The only problem with it is when `IComponent` is not the only interface and you have other abstract base classes that you want to derive from.  C# doesn't support multiple inheritance, and as an ex-C++ programmer I used to miss that a lot.  Not anymore.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution (which I would *not* generally recommend, but accomplishes what you are after) would be this.

```
public class Switch //make sealed if you really want to enforce behaviour
{  

    public bool IsEnabled {get; private set;}

    public void Enable() //make virtual if you don't want to enforce this behaviour
    { 
        IsEnabled = true;
    }

    public void Disable() //make virtual if you don't want to enforce this behaviour
    {
        IsEnabled = false;
    }
}

public interface IComponent {
    Switch Switch{get;}
}
```

Comment: @DocBrown I should be experienced enough not to post any code before testing it. (And certainly not before coffee). Thanks :)

Comment: Clever...but does not seem to have any advantages compared to just having a boolean get/set property?

Comment: @JacquesB I can't see any advantages either, but the OP admitted that the example was wonky.

Comment: @Guran sure, and I upvoted you for actually answering the question with a clever solution.

Comment: This is IMHO not particular useful. The requirement of the original interface was clearly to have `Enabled` and `Disabled` to be overrideable methods in an `IComponent`. You now get a "Switch" object completely decoupled from the `IComponent` object, and it can only switch the boolean flag, but nothing else inside the `IComponent` itself.  That does not look very sensible to me.

Comment: @DocBrown True. For this to do anything meaningful, the switch would need to expose events or some other means of callback. That is certainly doable but... as I wrote not recommended.

Comment: @Guran: I think in the current form, what you presented does not even accomplish of what the OP was after, recommended or not. But it inspired me for another approach, maybe I post another answer.

Comment: @DocBrown TBH I'm not really sure what the OP was after, since it looks like an XY problem. Looking forward to your take on it though.

Answer (score -1):

Simple answer: no.

That’s not what interfaces do. Each element of an interface is independent of every other element.  It is up to the implementor as to what happens when called.  Your interface can be implemented by anything, and what it does is up to concrete object.

The Disable method could do something entirely unrelated to the Enable method, and the IsEnabled property might return a value that is unrelated to either (for instance a constant value).

Simplest real world example — when your start implementing a interface, it is common to throw a not implemented exception.

It is up to the implementor to figure out how it all hangs together.